# how to redirect opener window

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook, popup

I am using fbconnect to login on my site by using the php-sdk. I want to close the popup window after getting user detail and redirect the opener window.

can anybody tell how it can be possible

Comment: functionality is like the yahoo facebook connect

Comment: javascript: window.close

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
window.opener.location.href = '/path/';
window.close();
```